# Is there a solution to Oracle Application Continuity not replaying inflight transactions for CLOB columns in JPA-based ORM?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, high-availability

Oracle Application Continuity is not working with CLOB columns when JPA is used as ORM.

Hi, we have implemented oracle application continuity as per the oracle documentation and used pooldatasource from ucp jar. We are using a CLOB column with JPA being our ORM. With CLOB column (irrespective of data available or not) as we switchover to different DB, a replay is not triggering and it is failing with connecition closed exception. If CLOB column is commented out, inflight transactions are being replayed as expected after DB switchover. This happens with JPA being the ORM.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.